# NodeJS mysql/xdevapi 'Access denied' using SSL and X Protocol

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to connect to my mysql server using the X Protocol and SSL.
To connect to a database I use the MySQL x devapi for NodeJs(mysql/xdevapi). Both, the MySQL server as well as my nodejs application are running on the same machine. However everytime I try to establish a connection I get the following error:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'accountservice'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at AuthenticationHandler.BaseHandler.<computed> (F:\Repositorys\Project\Application\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\ResponseHandlers\BaseHandler.js:113:19)
at Array.entry (F:\Repositorys\Project\Application\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\ResponseHandlers\BaseHandler.js:90:29)
at WorkQueue.process (F:\Repositorys\Project\Application\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\WorkQueue.js:75:19)
at Client.handleServerMessage (F:\Repositorys\Project\Application\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\Client.js:201:21)
at Client.handleNetworkFragment (F:\Repositorys\Project\Application\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\Client.js:245:14)
at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\Repositorys\Project\Application\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\Client.js:89:36)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:296:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10) {
 info: {
  severity: 0,
  code: 1045,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  msg: "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
 }
}
```

At first I thought maybe my password is wrong or my certificates are not valid but using
`mysql -u username -p --ssl-ca=/etc/certs/ca.pem --ssl-cert=../res/certs/mysql/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=../res/certs/mysql/client-key.pem` 
to login I get no error.

In addition to that, I also granted my user all privileges on all databases and tables to make sure missing privileges are not the reason for the failed connection.
The only possibility I can think of is that there is an error verifying the server's certificate, even though `openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem` returns `server-cert.pem: OK`.

To connect to the database I use the following code written in TypeScript

```
const conf = {
    host: 'localhost',//config.getHost(),
    port: 33060,//config.getPort(),
    user: 'username',//config.getUsername(),
    password: 'password',//config.getPassword(),
    schema: 'database',//config.getDatabase(),

    auth: 'SHA256_MEMORY', //removing this results in "Invalid authentication method PLAIN"

    ssl: {
        key: config.getCertKey(),
        cert: config.getCert(),
        ca: config.getCa()
    }
}

this.client = mysql.getClient(conf);
```

and

```
connect(next) {
    console.log('Connecting to database ' + this.config.getDatabase() + '(' + this.config.getHost() + ':' + this.config.getPort() + ')...');
    this.client.getSession().then(session => {
        this.session = session;
        console.log('Connection to database ' + this.config.getDatabase() + '(' + this.config.getHost() + ':' + this.config.getPort() + ') established.');
        listen(this, next);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Failed to establish connection to database ' + this.config.getDatabase() + '(' + this.config.getHost() + ':' + this.config.getPort() + ').');
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Maybe I missed a very important step, but at the moment I have no idea what causes this problem despite having read multiple answers on StackOverflow and other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public-key authentication is not a first-class API concern but nothing prevents you from providing the keys, in this case, under a `sslOptions` property (not the `ssl` property) in the configuration object. Those options will simply be merged when calling [`tls.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback). By contrast, there's API support for certificate authority validation, which in that case only requires you to define the path to the CA file (as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/tutorial-Secure_Sessions.html)).

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
const conf = {
  //...
  sslOptions: {
    // read contents of key.pem and cert.pem
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
    // path (only) to ca.pem
    ca: '/path/to/ca.pem'
  }
}
```

If you are using version 8.0.20 already, this flavour has been deprecated and you should instead use:

```
const conf = {
  //...
  tls: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
    ca: '/path/to/ca.pem'
  }
}
```

The reason you get the `Invalid authentication method PLAIN` error is because the client is naive and assumes that since `ssl` is not `true`, then it means TLS should be disabled, which does not work with `PLAIN`, the default authentication mechanism.

In any case, this should go away once you start using `sslOptions` instead.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer it now finally works. I also found the site you linked above and tried to use "tls", but I probably misspelled "tls", wrote "tsl" or something else and unfortunately never tried it again.....